# OpenTelemetry for WCF services hosted in IIS and Windows Services

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, open-telemetry

Currently, we have Thick Client (WPF application run in customer environment) and WCF services hosted in Cloud (as IIS/Windows services applications).

Thick Client runs from customer environment. It is always a pain to track issues related to Thick Client customer-facing issues. We are thinking to implement OpenTelemetry to tracking the end-to-end tracing/logs (WPF -> WCF) and also standardize the logging.

Is it a good idea to implement OpenTelemetry? I have seen a lot of samples related .net core but not WCF Services hosted in Windows Services. Please share any reference articles and best OpenTelemetry samples related to WPF -> WCF end-to-end tracing.